# Problemas em fazer consulta com NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho 3 usuários no banco de dados, e eu quero buscar por todos os usuários, menos o usuário 2, então tem que retornar o usuário 1 e 3. No banco de dados retorna perfeitamente, mas na web retorna sempre o usuário 1, e tem que ser o 1 e o 3. O código SQL que eu usei no PHP para retornar todos os usuários menos o com o id = 2 é:

```
$checkEmail = "SELECT email ";
$checkEmail .= "FROM usuariospf ";
$checkEmail .= "WHERE usuarioID NOT IN(2) ";
$queryEmail = mysqli_query($connection, $checkEmail);
if(!$queryEmail){
    die('Erro ao fazer a consulta!');
}
$users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail);
print_r($users);
```

Comment: Já olhou na documentação o que a função `mysqli_fetch_assoc` faz? Parece que está usando ela indevidamente.

Comment: Não relacionado ao problema em si,  mas vale notar que o IN faz sentido quando tem uma lista para comparar. Para um valor só, bastaria usar o sinal de diferente `usuarioID <> 2` ou mesmo `NOT usuarioID = 2` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 2):

Como comentado pelo colega Anderson, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` não faz o que você está esperando, e o resultado  que você obteve está corretíssimo (vem um por vez, e obviamente é o primeiro).

A resposta do colega Sam tem um exemplo de como usar a função em `loop`.

Se quer pegar todos os usuários de uma vez só, deve preferir a `função mysqli_fetch_all`:

```
$checkEmail = "SELECT email ";
$checkEmail .= "FROM usuariospf ";
$checkEmail .= "WHERE usuarioID <> 2";
$resultEmail = mysqli_query($connection, $checkEmail);
if(!$resultEmail){
    die('Erro ao fazer a consulta!');
}
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($resultEmail,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($users);
```

Manual:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Note o uso da opção `MYSQLI_ASSOC` para resultado associativo em vez de numérico.

Compare com o `fetch-assoc`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Caso dê erro de função inexistente, certifique-se do seu PHP estar usando a extensão `mysqlnd`. Caso não, procure usar desta forma:

```
$resultEmail->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Aproveitei para trocar o seu `NOT IN` por `WHERE usuarioID <> 2`. O `IN` faz sentido quando quiser usar uma lista de valores, como `WHERE usuarioID NOT IN (2, 3, 7)`

Comment: Curioso, tentei usar a função `mysqli_fetch_all` e dá o erro `Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()`, e estou usando PHP 7.... sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @Sam a extensão que tem a função é a "mysqlnd" (native driver), vem duas no PHP, nem  lembrava  disso.  Melhorei a resposta nesse sentido. Aproveitei e fiz uma menção ao loop do seu post

Answer (score 1):

A função `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` puxa cada linha encontrada na query cada vez que ela é chamada, ou seja:

```
-> mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail) // retorna o primeiro registro
-> mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail) // retorna o segundo registro
-> mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail) // retorna o terceiro registro
etc...
```

Como você só chamou uma vez em:

```
$users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail);
```

O valor de `$users` será o primeiro registro encontrado.

Para criar uma array com todos os registros, você pode criar um `while` alimentando a array chamando a função até o número de resultados encontrados. No final terá uma array associativa `$users[]` com todos os registros encontrados:

```
$checkEmail = "SELECT email ";
$checkEmail .= "FROM usuariospf ";
$checkEmail .= "WHERE usuarioID NOT IN(2) ";
$queryEmail = mysqli_query($connection, $checkEmail);
if(!$queryEmail){
  die('Erro ao fazer a consulta!');
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEmail)){
   $users[] = $row;
}
print_r($users);
```

Comment: Se usar `mysqli_fetch_all` você não precisará do laço, ela já retorna um *array* com todos os registros.